# blockchain - существует ли архив транзакций и как до него добратся

Tags: blockchain

Есть кошелёк на тестовом блокчейне, и на любом из сервисов работающих с testnet я нахожу что на него случилость только 2 транзакции, на ввод и на вывод средств. По данным, предоставленым мне, на этом адресе должно быть порядком больше транзакций, но я не могу их найти

Вот ссылка на него
https://blockstream.info/testnet/address/2MvvYEgXvTzCLDMPNPBB68boQTrkbpiBZh6

Мой вопрос в следующем: верно ли я понимаю, что если адрес вышел в 0, после того как на него прийдут средства, все транзакции до обнуления не становятся недоступны, или есть какой то архив, который нужно искать каким то особым образом?

Answer (score 1):

Все подтвержденные транзакции остаются в блокчейне навсегда. Это одна из ключевых идей блокчейна. Почему вы говорите, что транзакций только 2, если по вашей ссылке их 5?

Неподтвержденные транзакции не сохраняются. Возможно некоторые сервисы хранят их у себя некоторое время, но я не думаю, что кто-то делал такое для тестовой сети.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, я в этой теме совсем недавно, и могу упускать какие то базовые вещи, потому прошу прощения за возможно глупый вопрос.
Транзакций стало 5 так как я полез эксперементировать, и транзакций  и в правду прибавилось